# How to make sure packets from the same flow land on the same queue on two NICs when bridging

Tags: linux, tcp, network-programming, packet-capture

I'm writing a network bridge that reassembles and analyzes TCP flows on the fly. I have a pair of multi-queue NICS and I use [netmap](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/netmap/) to capture packets from each rx queues on different threads and than pass them on to the other NIC for transmission. The problem is, packets from the same flow do not land on the same queue on the two NICs, due to the source and destination addresses and port being reversed.

I tried ethtool to change the tuple the hash of which is used for distributing packets. Running this:

```
# ethtool --show-nfc p1p1 rx-flow-hash tcp4
```

results in:

```
TCP over IPV4 flows use these fields for computing Hash flow key:
IP SA
IP DA
L4 bytes 0 & 1 [TCP/UDP src port]
L4 bytes 2 & 3 [TCP/UDP dst port]
```

Repeating the above command for the other NIC results in the same queue. I thought I could change the order for one of the rings by running `ethtool --config-nfc p1p1 rx-flow-hash tcp4 dsfn` but that doesn't change the order of the fields used in the hash. It seems that both `sdfn` and `dsfn` result in the same tuple. The same is true for `ds` and `sd`.

Is there a way to make the packets in one flow always land on the same queue (and the same thread) on both NICs whether using `ethtool` to configure the NICs or otherwise another method or tool?

Comment: If your card supports n-tuple hashing, you could specify the exact mapping you want from destination/source IP address and port to queue number.